# Could not connect to development server [React-Native]

Tags: react-native, server

I create a vanilla react-native application, then I run it using Xcode and the react-terminal window opened but when I try to enable "Fast refresh" from app-in-menu it doesn't show the option, so I tap on "Configure Bundle" using IP: 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and PORT: 8081.
This is the error that occur:[image]

I've reinstall nodeJs, npm and clean caches, but nothing It doesn't work. How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you run `npm start` before?

Comment: hey thank you, yes I did.

Comment: Are you using real device?

Comment: yes, I'm -------

Comment: Do your phone and computer use the same network?

Comment: yes -----------

Comment: I've get it, the error was with the installation, instead of using all other commands user: npx-create-react-native-app"